# Java Debugger runs application without breaking

Tags: java, debugging, command-line, jdb, throwable

I have the ubiquitous HelloWorldApp.java file

```
/**
 * The HelloWorldApp class implements an application that
 * simply prints "Hello World!" to standard output.
 */
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I run:

```
javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

then I run:

```
jdb HelloWorldApp
```

I get:

```
Initializing jdb ...
>
```

I type:

```
stop at HelloWorldApp.main:7
```

where prompted

then I get

```
Deferring breakpoint HelloWorldApp.main:7.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
>
```

I type:

```
run
```

where prompted

then I get

```
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: Hello World!

The application exited
```

I didn't type anything on that last prompt it just exited without breaking. My question is why did it output those Throwable lines and why didn't the debugger stop at the breakpoint I gave it?

Comment: What is line 7? Is it line 7 in the file or line 7 in main? If it's the later, there is no line 7 in main.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked the syntax for stop in JDB Documentation

```
stop in <class-name>.<method-name>  Stop on entry to the given method.
stop at <class-name>:<line-number>  Stop at the given line.
```

I think you command for stop should be either one of the following

```
stop in HelloWorldApp.main 
stop at HelloWorldApp:7
```

Give it a try to see that fixes your issue!

Comment: read websites explaining jdb none of them were helpful. Thanks Ganesh for your help.

Comment: @mpdunson BTW, this is my first encounter with Java Debugger! :-)